# How to use database in an Asynctask

Tags: android, sqlite, google-maps, android-asynctask

I have this codes

```
public  ArrayList<StationData> getAllStations(String num1){

    ArrayList<StationData> stationData = new ArrayList<>();


    Cursor cursor = mydb.rawQuery(" select * from   Stations where lines like '%"+num1+"%'   ORDER BY id DESC", null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("id"));
            char faName =  (char)(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
            char enName = (char) (cursor.getColumnIndex("enName"));
            char lines = (char)(cursor.getColumnIndex("lines"));
            char address = (char) (cursor.getColumnIndex("address"));
            float latitude = cursor.getFloat(cursor.getColumnIndex("latitude"));
            float longitude = cursor.getFloat(cursor.getColumnIndex("longitude"));
            StationData hh = new StationData(id, faName, enName, lines, address, latitude, longitude);

            stationData.add(hh);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        cursor.close();

    }else{

    }
    return stationData;
}
```

and this is my AsyncTask

```
  class MetroLineMaker extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{

        MetroDataBase metroDataBase = new MetroDataBase(getApplicationContext());
        ArrayList<StationData> metroData;
        StationData stationData = new StationData();
//        metroData = new ArrayList<>();

        protected void onPreExecute() {

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {


            metroData = metroDataBase.getAllStations(strings[0]);

            for (int i=0;i<metroData.size()-1 ;i++) {

                LatLng last = new LatLng(metroData.get(i).getLatitude(), metroData.get(i).getLongitude());
                LatLng next = new LatLng(metroData.get(i + 1).getLatitude(), metroData.get(i + 1).getLongitude());

//                    createMarker(metroData.get(i).getLatitude(), metroData.get(i).getLongitude());


                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(metroData.get(i).getLatitude(), metroData.get(i).getLongitude()))
                        .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.ic_metro_line_one)));


                mMap.addPolyline(
                        new PolylineOptions().add(
                                last, next
                        ).width(10).color(Color.RED)
                );


            }


            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        }
    }
```

and I have this errors

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
>                     Process: com.arnaway.metromap, PID: 9493
>                     java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
>                         at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:353)
>                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
>                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
>                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
>                         at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
>                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
>                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
>                         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
>                      Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
>                         at com.arnaway.metromap.MainActivity$MetroLineMaker.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1028)
>                         at com.arnaway.metromap.MainActivity$MetroLineMaker.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1013)
>                         at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
>                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>                         at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245) 
>                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
>                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
>                         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

how can I use my database in an AsyncTask and show my marker in MainActivity my AsyncTask is in MainActivity too.

Comment: in which line is the error ? you should check if the cursor.getCount > 0 or not